# Can I regain my old WhatsApp account after I changed my phone number?

Tags: whatsapp

I have used WhatsApp which I registerd in my old SIM card. However, I changed the SIM card and the old SIM card is no longer available.

Usually, if you launch the app after you change your SIM card, the app first asks you to change the phone number as well. However, the problem is my iPhone was too buggy so I restored it after I changed the SIM card but before I opened the app. After the restore, when I opened the app, the app asks me to log in using the phone verification, but I can't log in since I no longer have the old SIM card.

In this case, can I still regain my old WhatsApp account? I feel that there is no way to regain it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per this [WhatsApp page](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/bb/22374588?_fb_noscript=1):

> If you changed your phone number and kept your same BlackBerry, you
>   can change your number within WhatsApp. Before proceeding, make sure
>   that your current number is activated on your phone and that you can
>   receive SMS messages and phone calls.
>
> Using the Change Number feature in WhatsApp will:
>
> - Migrate your account information (including your profile information), groups and settings from your old phone number to your
>     new phone number; and
> - Delete the account associated with your old phone number, so your contacts can no longer see your old phone number in their lists of
>     WhatsApp contacts.
>
> If you use our Change Number feature, your chat history will continue
>   to be available on your phone with the new phone number as long as you
>   continue using the same phone.
>
> Please make sure your WhatsApp contacts have your new phone number
>   saved in their phone’s address books to ensure a seamless messaging
>   experience.

This situation presumes that you still have access to your WhatsApp account.

If you have a new SIM, here's the process recommended by WhatsApp (see [page](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/27585377/?category=5245246)):

> To change your phone number within WhatsApp, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Insert the new SIM card with the new number into your device.
> 2. Open WhatsApp.
> 3. Check if your old phone number is currently verified. You can see what number is verified in WhatsApp by navigating to WhatsApp >
>      Menu Button > Settings and tapping on your profile photo.
> 4. Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Account > Change number.
> 5. Enter your old phone number in the top box.
> 6. Enter your new phone number in the bottom box.
> 7. Tap Done at the top of the screen.
> 8. You will be prompted to verify your new phone number.

This page has additional information your various varieties of phone types (iOS, Android, etc.).

Comment: The first link is broken.