# How can I choose which Google Drive' backup WhatsApp uses?

Tags: whatsapp

I have two phones.

On one of them(PhoneA) I did a backup of WhatsApp data to a google account.

On another(PhoneB) I did a backup of WhatsApp data to a different google account.

And as a test, I have a google drive account with both backups.

If I uninstall WhatsApp on phoneB, and reinstall WhatsApp, it asks me if I want to restore the backup... It only offers me the backup of phoneB.  But I want to restore the WhatsApp backup from PhoneA to PhoneB.

How can I do that?

Comment: and both Phones has same (or different) google account? sign off from your google account on PhoneB and sign in with google account where you have both backups

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a phone application, not a web application

Comment: @ChrisF have you not heard of android.stackexchange? You should vote for it to be migrated to android.stackexchange

Comment: @barlop - I have, but I'm always wary of migrations.

Comment: @ChrisF  no need now, i've just asked on there.

Answer (score 1):

- grab your **PhoneB** and logout from your "**PhoneB google account**"
- then on your **PhoneB** login with your "**PhoneA google account**" (or google account where you have both backups)
- do your restore by deploying **PhoneA** backup on your **PhoneB** phone
- done (and switch google accounts again if needed)

Comment: where is the option to sign in or out?

Comment: @barlop well, that depends on what android version you have, but roughtly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJdPXxvX7hM

Comment: That link is how to remove a google account from your phone. I know how to do that. What you are suggesting is I should delete all google accounts and adding one, that one whatsapp will use.  Then installing whatsapp for the restore.   Then adding them all back. That adding all google accounts back having deleted them, is a really time consuming workaround.  I want all the google accounts on my phone. You're essentially saying No you can't choose which google account to use. You have to delete all but one.

Comment: it doesnt work when the mobile number is different  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/k-hmECe16g8  error of "no backup found for this account"  This may be relevant too https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/110798/can-i-regain-my-old-whatsapp-account-after-i-changed-my-phone-number?rq=1